# Runs in gdb but not out of gdb

Tags: gcc, x86, gdb, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am trying to spawn a shell with some shellcode. The payload is in the program itself, however, when I run then program individually I get a segmentation fault, but when running in gdb, my shell opens.
Can someone point out what the problem might be?

```
MrMox@ubuntu:~/folder$ ./a.out h h
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

MrMox@ubuntu:~/folder$ gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from /home/folder/a.out...done.
(gdb) run h h
Starting program: /home/folder/a.out h h
process 22119 is executing new program: /bin/dash
$ 
$
```

Comment: I had a Heisenbug like that once. It was undefined behavior, caused by heap corruption. Be thankful it's reproducible. I suggest you narrow the code down to a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org), post that and we'll try to spot the bug.

Answer (score 3):

> what the problem might be

First, since you do get a `core`, you could just look in it to understand the crash.

Second, GDB disables address randomization ([ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)) by default (to make it easier for you to debug, so everything stays in one place), whereas running `a.out` outside of GDB likely has full ASLR, which possibly explains the different behavior of `a.out` with and without GDB.

You can disable ASLR globally:

```
sudo -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space"
```

Or you can enable randomization within GDB:

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization off
```