# c++ bad_alloc, but it disappear in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, backtrace, bad-alloc

I have a big project, compiles fine, but sometimes when I run in terminal(sometimes not)

```
./run
```

it gives bad_alloc exception, so i think it might be helpful to backtrace using gdb, so I do

```
gdb ./run
run
```

and it weirdly exit normally, nothing wrong shows up, even though I tried a lot of times.
Has someone met similar issues before?

Comment: *I have a big project, compiles fine,* -- "Compiling fine" only means your program has no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether your program is logically correct.

Comment: true, this project was running well until last week I made a few changes. But when I look back, trying to debug I couldn't locate where the issue happens, because bad_alloc does not provide information on where it happens, also sometimes it works sometimes not.

Comment: Apply changes slowly and test carefully between each step. Makes it easier to isolate what inserted or exposed the bug. I don't suppose we can get an [mcve]?

Comment: probably not because the project is too big, and hard to locate where the problem happens, it involves over 20 cpp/.h files and multiple APIs

Comment: I think y'all are way to quick to close this question. Even though there is no MCVE, a useful answer can still be provided.

Comment: welcome to the world of stackover flow, where no question can be posted without MCVE. Anyway thanks a lot Employed Russian, it helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21896928/50617) for what may be different "inside" vs. "outside" of GDB, and what to do about it.

If you can enable core dumps (`ulimit -c unlimited`), that should give you another way to get the stack trace.

In my experience, most `bad_alloc`s result from one of two root causes:

1. Uninitialized size:

   `int size;
   if (something) {
     // assign to size here
   }
   std::vector v(size);  // Oops: size may be unintialized.`
2. Arithmetic underflow:

   `std::vector v(other_vector.size() - 20);`

   Here, if `other_vector.size() < 20`, you'll get humongous value.

Comment: found the problem, it was because uninitialized bool variable, so undefined behavior(could be true/false randomly)

Comment: i guess gdb set all uninitialized bool variable to true? that's why it always exit normally in gdb

Comment: @TomDawn GDB doesn't do that. But disabling randomization (which GDB does do) can affect what value a random memory byte has, and thus may make the problem deterministically reproducible or irreproducible.